# For Windows Server Failover Cluster, How exactly does the system know when to failover to the standby node?

Tags: failover, failovercluster

Just to check with you guys how does the system know when to failover to the standby node?
For example, if an Application crash on primary node, will the system failover to standby node by purely detecting the process of the application? If is out from the process at task manager means it will failover to standby node to re-launch the application?

Comment: Your question is not clear, a real-life example would be helpful.

Comment: Alright let me try to add in example, sorry it might not be a good example im just trying to understand how the system detect abnormalities(like hardware fault or application crash) to perform failover

Comment: Heartbeat monitor?

Comment: @LastTribunal, sorry as im still quite new to failover. How exactly does heartbeat monitor? For example if is application crash, what area do the heartbeat monitor to know is down and failover to secondary/standby node?

Comment: Heartbeat monitor monitors IP, not application.  It pings, and if the pings timeout, it will faileover

Comment: @LastTribunal, okay then how about application/hardware fault or crash? Where does it monitor to know it is down and perform failover to standby node?

Comment: Hardware crash of a node will cause a ping timeout, app crash will not, and it will not cause a failover

Comment: @LastTribunal, thanks for the explanation. That's strange because i saw some failover solution like Veritas cluster or Microsoft failover clustering saying it can detect application crash and perform failover to restart the application. Thus, i am wondering how do they know or where they monitor to know that the application on primary node is down and thus perform failover?

Comment: Auto-failover is meant to address cluster node failure, not the apps that the nodes are hosting.  You can however trigger a failover based on any event.  In the case you are mentioning, the the trigger is likely a failure of a PID or an actual service.  A MS cluster service will force a restart of a crashed app (stopped service), but not a failover.

Comment: With that being said, only hardware/node failure will trigger auto-failover? I was confused when MS cluster solution or Veritas cluster say no data lost, can detect application down and bring it back up in time to avoid data lost

Comment: Data loss is a separate subject from clustering.  Data loss occurs when you loose the database due to corruption of deletion.  Then you have to consider RPO and RTO.  Clustering only addresses RTO..